# Getting "Package not found:" error while creating a .txt file in python

Tags: python, arrays, file-handling

I am trying to create a 4 Dimensional array using 'np.zeros' function and then reshaping it into my required dimension size(s) respectively.

Then, I further proceeded to store the contents of this 4D array into a separate output.txt file, but on creation, it is showing an error by the name "Package not found:" and highlighting the individual elements that I have attempted to write to the text file.
I have written a function for the same purpose. The implementation is given below:

```
fp = "output.txt"  # naming the file in the same directory
arr = np.zeros(3000)  # creating an array of zeros
arr = np.reshape(arr, (10, 10, 3, 10))  # reshaping the array of zeros into a 4D array


def create_table(array, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w') as f:
        # loop over each element in the 4D array
        for i in range(array.shape[0]):
            for j in range(array.shape[1]):
                for k in range(array.shape[2]):
                    # writing values of i, j, k indices once
                    f.write(f"X:{i}\t Y:{j}\t Z:{k}\n")
                    for l in range(array.shape[3]):
                        # writing every value that 4th dimension of the array possesses
                        f.write(f"{array[i, j, k, l]}\n")


create_table(arr, fp)
```

Below is the description of the error being thrown:

> Package not found: '0.0'

I thought it was a problem regarding not using the str() function but even that did not help. I had earlier tried to directly open file without passing the file_path as a parameter, so I thought maybe that was causing some issue, so created that parameter and tried that approach. Also, I do not know if the requirements.txt file has any role to play with this problem as I have not used that file in my project and it wasn't an issue up until now as well.
I tried, to the best of my knowledge, to search for any relevant problem and would be really grateful if anyone could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: please add the full stacktrace you are getting when the error occurs

Comment: @Nullman There isn't a thread dump (or I'm not completely sure about it but unable to find it), it is being shown under the problems section in the txt file on pycharm

Comment: we can't really help you much more without further details. what happans when you run your code? could it be that you are experiencing [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-53909) bug?

Comment: Thanks but no, it doesn't help me. Its just showing 3000 errors with "Package not found: '0.0'". I am unable to understand why is txt file creation causing this

Comment: without more info we can't help you. double check that numpy is installed and if you have multiple python environments (venv/anaconda) make sure you are using the correct one and that your packages are installed in it and not just in the system level python

Comment: I'm using pipenv and yes numpy is there in the python packages installed :(    Thanks for trying though